# Two forms in django templates without conflict

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-forms

I'm creating a template with two different forms but I have the following problem: when I submit the first one the second is also validated and get validation errors. What can I do to avoid this conflict?

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the [prefix argument](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) on your forms